# font-size not looking same in pixels and em

Tags: css, font-size

I have a [webpage](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) made by me in which I have put "Frontend Developer" text twice on the laptop image so that I can compare the font-size in pixels and em.

For the upper "Frontend Developer" text, I have put `font-size: 2.875em` whereas for the lower "Frontend Developer" text, I have put `font-size: 46px`

> I am wondering why font-sizes for both of the text are not looking
>   similar ? Although 46px=2.875em (font size)

The CSS code for both of the text are:

```
.frontend-background-image p:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 2.875em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.frontend-background-image p:nth-child(2) {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size: 46px;
}
```

Comment: Link broken can u use jsfiddle or run it using the code part?

Comment: @MohamedAdel Check now

Answer (score 4):

`em` is a relative unit, meaning when you ay `2.875em`, you mean 2.875 times whatever the font size would have been to start with. 46px is 2.875em...if your base size is 16px. The fact that the other text is showing up at a different size means your base size must be something else.

When you're inspecting elements in dev tools, you can look at the 'computed' tab to see what font size is actually rendering. In your case, that line is coming out at about 40px.

You can change the baseline the `em` is relative to by setting a font-size on the parent. In your case, for example, if you add:

`.frontend-background-image { font-size: 16px; }`

it'll make the math equal out, and will make both of these lines of text the same size.

Comment: It worked but in some other cases the font-sizes are not the same if I am using em instead of pixels. The pixels is showing different size in comparison to em.

Comment: How can I tackle that issue ?

Comment: @In the text `Frontend Developer At Homesail` I am facing the same issue at line#78(`font-size: 1.750em;`)  of css file. Do I need to remove `font-size: 1.2em;` at line#73 to make it work ?

Comment: I am very much new to rem/em. rem/em is confusing me very much. Should I go with pixels for font-size ?

Comment: If you want to keep it simple while you're getting started, pixels are the most straightforward. It'll also be easiest if you avoid "stacking" ems on elements and their children. You can find plenty of information and helpful guides on this subject if you search 'css sizing px em' - CSS Tricks probably has a good reference page on the topic.

Comment: @Yeah, I will keep it simple. I will go with pixels for font size.